# Export x509 Certificate from iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, keychain, certificate, ssl

**Question:** Is there a way to export a public certificate from an iPad running the latest iOS? (PEM formatted Base64 if possible)

**Scenario:**

AirWatch manages our iPads.

There is a profile configured to request and install an x509 certificate on each iPad.  These certificates originate from a public Certificate Authority, and are obtained when AirWatch submits a CSR for the iPad to the CA via AirWatch's configured "Registration Authority".

A problem has been brought to my attention, and I need to export one of the certificates (just the public certificate, not the private key) from the affected iPad.

However, for the life of me I cannot find any documentation from Apple about how to accomplish this, and after searching for several days, I've accepted that my Google-Fu has failed me.

I would be most thankful for any light someone could shed on my predicament.